# Finding the tangent space of a subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

My professor set the following question and I have an answer, though would like someone with more experience to cast a critical eye over the details as I don't necessarily trust my result!

Define the following set of $2\times 2$ invertible matrices:

$$S=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} \;:\; a,b \in \mathbb{R} \;\text{with}\;  a\neq 0\right\}.$$

Firstly, I can prove that this is a subgroup of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ by showing that for any $A,B\in S$, $AB\in S$ and $A^{-1}\in S$. The next part of the question then asks to define a suitable curve in $S$ and find $T_{e}S$, the tangent space at the identity. So I defined
\begin{eqnarray*} 
   \gamma: I\subset\mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow& S \\
    t &\longmapsto& A = \gamma(t) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{at} & 0 \\ bt & e^{at} \end{pmatrix} \end{eqnarray*}
With this definition, $\gamma(t)\in S$ and $\gamma(0)=I_{2}$, the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Then
$$ \gamma'(t) = \begin{pmatrix} ae^{at} & 0 \\ b & ae^{at} \end{pmatrix} $$
and 
$$ \gamma'(0) = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}. $$
Thus the tangent space is
$$ T_{e}S = \{ \gamma'(0) \;:\; \gamma(0)=I_{2} \} = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} \;:\; a,b \in \mathbb{R} \;\text{with}\;  a\neq 0\right\} = S. $$

This seems to indicate that the tangent space to $S$ at the identity is $S$! This seems odd to me. Any observations/comments/questions/hints would be most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You "forgot" a few curves and tangent vectors.

$T_eS$ must be a two-dimensional vector space, but $S$ is not (but almost :-), We have, for example, $0\not\in S.$ To remedy this, put $a = 0$ in your curve $\gamma$. Please check that this is perfectly valid. We still have
$$
\gamma(t) \in S,\quad \gamma(0) = I_2,
$$
and in particular
$$\gamma'(t) = \begin{pmatrix} ae^{at} & 0 \\ b & ae^{at} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \gamma'(0).
$$
So we see that allowing the parameter $a = 0$ for the curves $\gamma$ provides exactly the missing elements of $TeS.$ Now we know that
$$
U := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}u & 0 \\ v & u \end{pmatrix} \ \mid\ u,v \in \mathbb R\right\} \subseteq T_eS,
$$
and since $U$ is indeed a real vector space with $\dim U = 2 = \dim S = \dim T_eS$ (please check that), we must have equality.
$$
U = T_eS.
$$
We note that we have
$$
S \subseteq T_eS,
$$
but that's not so uncommon. It's also true for $GL_n(\mathbb R):$
$$
GL_n(\mathbb R) \subseteq T_eGL_n(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R^{n\times n}.
$$

Comment: Ah I think I see what are saying. I was under the illusion that you had to define just one arbitrary curve that would lie in $S$, but in actually fact you have to define curves that would account for all possible element in $S$. Is that a correct statement?

Comment: Yes. One curve produces just one tangent vector. To be sure that you got the whole tangent space in this way, you should always check that the set of tangent vectors you produced is a vector space and has the right dimension.

Comment: Cool. And when you say it has the "right dimension", how do we know what the dimension of the subspace must be? I guess it is related to the group $S$, but how is the dimension of a group defined? I guess it is two dimensional as there are two free constants leading to a basis of two matrices.

Comment: $S$ is a Lie group, and as such a differentiable manifold. The dimension of the tangent space at any point of a manifold is the same as the dimension of the manifold. The dimension of a manifold can be determined from its definition. Looking at the defintion of $S$ from your question, we see that we have a "diffeomorphism" $\varphi: S\rightarrow \mathbb R^2,{a\ 0\choose b\ a} \mapsto (a,b).$ This means that $S$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are "the same thing" when viewed as differentiable manifolds. Since we know, that $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension $2$, we get that $S$ has dimension $2$.

Answer (score 0):

So let me just summarize what I (think) have learnt:

Let $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ (which includes $\alpha=0$) and define the curves
\begin{align*}
   \gamma_{1}:I\subset \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow S \qquad &\gamma_{2}:I\subset \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow S \\
   t &\longmapsto \gamma_{1}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{\alpha t} & 0 \\ \beta t & e^{\alpha t} \end{pmatrix} \qquad &t &\longmapsto \gamma_{2}(t)=\begin{pmatrix} -e^{\alpha t} & 0 \\ \beta t & -e^{\alpha t} \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

This accounts for all possible curves with values in $S$. However, since $\gamma_{2}(0)\neq I_{2}$, this curve will not be in the tangent space $T_{e}S$. Then since
\begin{eqnarray*}
   \gamma_{1}'(t) &=& \begin{pmatrix} \alpha e^{\alpha t} & 0 \\ \beta & \alpha e^{\alpha t} \end{pmatrix} \qquad\Longrightarrow \qquad \gamma_{1}'(0) = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix},
\end{eqnarray*}
the tangent space is given by:
\begin{eqnarray*}
   T_{e}S = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ \beta & \alpha \end{pmatrix} \;:\; \alpha,\beta \in S \right\}.
\end{eqnarray*}